# Facebook like doesn't point to correct url

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-like

i try to add facebook like button on my root domain that will like to other page on site. but everytime i hit like button, it always like root domain. where am i go wrong?

here is the code for like button :

```
<fb:like action='like' colorscheme='light' expr:href='http://www.kliniksantai.com/2012/06/7-ciri-ciri-pria-tidak-dewasa.html' font='arial' layout='standard' send='true' show_faces='false'/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the updated version:

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.kliniksantai.com/2012/06/7-ciri-ciri-pria-tidak-dewasa.html" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>`

Don't forget to include the JS SDK as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).